# Parameterized file/folder path in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, parameterized

Is there any way to parameterized the folder/file path in Jmeter?

When the user uploading it to jenkins or sending to another user it will be very handy if that can be possible

Answer (score 0):

1. If your test relies on external files (i.e. uses [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) or uploads files using [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler) the good practices is using [relative paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths), to wit not hard-coding the full path to the folder/file but rather using a relative path to the .jmx file, this way you will be able to transfer the script across machines, use it for [distributed testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter/) or in continuous integration servers without having to change anything
2. Any path can be set via JMeter Property using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P), this way you will be able to [override the property value using `-J` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)
3. If your test data represents a folder with multiple files you might be interested in [Directory Listing Config](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/directory-listing/DirectoryListing.md) plugin